# Proof of Spin commutation relation for Holstein-Primakoff-Transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-spin, commutator

I have run into an issue while trying to prove the Holstein-Primakoff commutations

\begin{align*}
 [S^+_i,S^-_j]=2 \delta_{ij} S^z_i, \ [S^z_i, S^-_j]=-\delta_{ij} S^-_i 
\end{align*}

where

\begin{align*}
 S^+_i&=\sqrt{2S - n_i} a_i,            \\ 
 S^-_i&=a^{\dagger}_i \sqrt{2S - n_i},  \\
 S^z_i&=S - n_i,                        \\
 n_i&=a^{\dagger}_i a_i.
\end{align*}

Using commutator rules I get

\begin{align*}
 [S^+_i, S^-_i]
=\sqrt{2S - n_i} [a_i, a^+_j \sqrt{2S - n_j}]
 + [\sqrt{2S - n_i}, a^+_j \sqrt{2S-n_j}] a_i
=\sqrt{2S - n_i}
 \left([a_i, a^+_j] \sqrt{2S - n_j} + a^+_j [a_i, \sqrt{2S - n_j}] \right) \\
 +\left([\sqrt{2S - n_i}, a^+_j] \sqrt{2S - n_j}
   + a^+_j [\sqrt{2S - n_i}, \sqrt{2S - n_j}]\right) 
  a_i
\end{align*}

However when I try to evaluate the commutators further using $[a_i, a^+_j]=\delta_{ij}$ and the definition of the commutator I get

$$
[S^+_i, S^-_i]=\sqrt{2S - n_i} a_i a^+_j \sqrt{2S - n_j}
               - a^+_j \sqrt{2S - n_j} \sqrt{2S - n_i} a_i.
$$

which is correct (it is the definition of the commutator) but not the expected result. Where  am I going wrong? How can I actually get the intended result?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holstein–Primakoff_transformation). Have you mastered just one oscillator?

Comment: But you have to take into account that $n=a^{\dagger}a$ and it is also the operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof** $[S_j^z,\,S_j^{\pm}]=\pm S_j^{\pm}$

$$[S^z,S^{+}]=[S-n,\sqrt{2S-n}a]=-[n,\sqrt{2S-n}a]=\\=-(\sqrt{2S-n}[n,a]+[n,\sqrt{2S-n}]a)=\\=-\sqrt{2S-n}[n,a]=+\sqrt{2S-n}\,a=S^{+},$$
$$[S^{z},S^{-}]=[S-n,a^{\dagger}\sqrt{2S-n}]=-[n,a^{\dagger}\sqrt{2S-n}]=\\=-(a^{\dagger}[n,\sqrt{2S-n}]+[n,a^{\dagger}]\sqrt{2S-n})=\\=-[n,a^{\dagger}]\sqrt{2S-n}=-S^{-}.$$

**Proof** $[S^{+}_j,S^{-}_j]=2S^{z}_j$

$$[S^{+},S^{-}]=[\sqrt{2S-n}a,\,a^{\dagger}\sqrt{2S-n}]=\\=\sqrt{2S-n}[a,\,a^{\dagger}\sqrt{2S-n}]+[\sqrt{2S-n},\,a^{\dagger}\sqrt{2S-n}]a=\\=\sqrt{2S-n}\left(a^{\dagger}[a,\sqrt{2S-n}]+\sqrt{2S-n}\,a\right)+\\+[\sqrt{2S-n},a^{\dagger}]\sqrt{2S-n}a=\\=\sqrt{2S-n}\left\{a^{\dagger}\left(a\sqrt{2S-n}-\sqrt{2S-n}\,a\right)+\sqrt{2S-n}\right\}+\\+\left(\sqrt{2S-n}\,a^{\dagger}-a^{\dagger}\sqrt{2S-n}\right)\sqrt{2S-n}\,a=\\=(1+n)(2S-n)-a^{\dagger}(2S-n)\,a=\\=(1+n)(2S-n)-a^{\dagger}a(2S-(n-1))=\\=(1+n)(2S-n)-n(2S-n+1)=\\=2(S-n)\equiv 2S^z.$$

Due to the presence of $\delta_{ij}$ it is convenient to consider $j$-site only and omit $j$ index for clearer notation. Also, I have omitted hats, i.e. $n$ means $\hat{n}$.